# Editing existing Group Policy using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have been created on my DC Group Policy which creates Schedule Task.

My question - How can I edit the command action inside the Schedule Task using PowerShell?

Answer (score -1):

Do this via [New-ScheduledTaskAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskaction?view=windowsserver2019-ps) and [Set-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/set-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' -Argument '-Command Example-Command'
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'ExistingTaskName' -Action $action
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it isn't editing Group Policy it's edit a local schedule task